# The reputation log shows weird(and wrong) values

Tags: support, bug, reputation

I just looked at the reputation log and saw that I got +203 and +114 on a question and answer.

I haven't seen this kind of thing happen before, it looks like it's summed all the upvotes of the question and answer, but it's still wrong (25 upvotes = 250 - 2(serial downvotes...) = **246** and not **203** ).

[image]

Is it a bug?

[(the question and answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10433014/601179)

---

**Update:**

O.K. As detective @animuson found out, the values are correct..., but why did I see the total votes sum, and not the current votes sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the votes were not counted or counted for partial due to a reputation cap.

On May 3 alone (the day you posted), 4 of your question upvotes and 1 answer upvote did not count at all, as well one of the question upvotes only counted for 1. Also, on May 8, one answer upvote counted for 7 and one answer and one question upvote did not count. Here's a detailed listing of the votes for that question:

**Question upvotes:**

```
May 3
--------
+5 (x8 = +40)
+1
+0 (x4 = +0)

May 4
--------
+5 (x5 = +25)

May 8
--------
+5
+0

May 9
--------
+0

May 10
--------
+5 (x4 = +20)

May 12
--------
+5

May 16
--------
+5
-2

May 18
--------
+0

May 19
--------
+5 (x3 = +15)

TOTAL: 114 (+31 votes, -1 vote = 30 score)
```

**Answer upvotes:**

```
May 3
--------
+10 (x9 = +90)
+0

May 4
--------
+10 (x4 = +40)

May 8
--------
+7
+0

May 9
--------
+0

May 10
--------
+10 (x4 = +40)

May 16
--------
+10
-2 (x2 = -4)

May 18
--------
+0

May 19
--------
+10 (x2 = +20)

TOTAL: 203 (+25 votes, -2 votes = 23 score)
```

Comment: WOW a detective work! how did you find this info?

Comment: Go to your reputation history, start at the day the question and answer were created, find the title in each day, expand each one to see all the votes.

Comment: Is this the way you did it? I appreciate the effort! Anyway, why did it sum the score? is it a new feature? it's the first time I see it...

Comment: I don't know the exact way the drop-down thingy works, but usually if it keeps receiving consistent votes over a period of time, it will keep adding the new votes to the total rather than resetting the value to 0 in that view. If your question went without receiving votes for about a week (guess), it would probably reset that value to 0 as expected.

Comment: I got now one more upvote on the Q&A, and I see only +10 and +5 in the dropdown. Maybe the SE team can explain that thing.

Comment: Had you previously checked your reputation to clear out the changes, or was it still queued back to May 3rd (or whenever the last time you checked it was)?

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't get the question. :(

Comment: When you go to your profile; if you haven't checked your reputation it will have the total change in the tab there. Once you've checked, it goes away. Maybe it's related to when you actually check your history? Just a thought.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. I look there almost every day. Maybe a recalc happend or something like it?