# I got 98 rep because a user was deleted?

Tags: bug, status-declined, reputation, activity-dropdown

This is a bug on the system rather than I ranting about getting the +98 reps.

[image: Snapshout!]

I'm perfectly aware about the [obscure magic behind the entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126471/213575). BTW, in my user page it appears just -2 so it's alright. [The account is on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/792066/braiam?tab=reputation).

What I'm trying to get across is that in both, my Reputation tab/info and the popup should be in *sync* about the information of my reputation.

Comment: Tangentially related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178687/user-delete-events-are-merged-in-the-activity-reputation-drop-down-thingymajig, system events get merged...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug has been obsoleted by the new top bar.

Answer (score 24):

This appears to be a combination of two system events. The Association Bonus on your account gave you the +100 and you recently has a User was removed event for -2, which adds up to +98.

Since both of these events are not actually related to a specific post and wouldn't have any sort of ID connected to them, the system that is checking for recent reputation changes is probably seeing the lack of ID on both events and connecting them as the same event, and thus combining their reputation values. Since logically the system thinks these are both on the same "post," it probably only even does anything with the title for the most recent one.

I'm not really sure whether the dev team considers this a bug or not. I don't really see any use in displaying system events such as these in the recent reputation drop-down.

Comment: Well, they weren't on the same day, also there are several entries prior/post the _User deleted_ event, but you are right, those system calculations ain't wood for the drop-down (or popup?)

Comment: @Braiam: No one really knows exactly how the drop-down determines what is considered "recent reputation activity" but I have seen instances where events from up to a week ago were included in the calculation. It's a bit random.

Comment: Dang, obscure magic follows me around, I might pissed some voodoo medic without noticing.

Comment: That would have been awesome if a user was removed and the +98 was because 49 down-votes were reversed.

Comment: As for the randomness: [Reputation Activity in User Dropdown Incorrect/Inconsistent?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130119/reputation-activity-in-user-dropdown-incorrect-inconsistent) But no explanation there either ;-)

Comment: @Aaron what about down voting 98 questions fromthe user?

Comment: @Cole well, I suppose the OP here could have down-voted 98 of the removed user's *answers*, but somehow that seems less funny (and less likely to have caused confusion).